# Error in call child window function in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using the iframe inside the thickbox and calling the function in thickbox that is iframe but it is not working.How can I call it that will work in all browser.I am using this function

```
 window.frames[0].test();
```

sometimes it worked in firefox not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cross-domain scripting problem.  Try setting the following in javascript in both the child and parent page:

```
document.domain = "example.com"
```

Comment: No.both are in the same domain.